# How to call an jenkins url with authentication parameters in meteor?

Tags: node.js, http, meteor, jenkins

I have an jenkins url which requires login to view the contents. In my project i have to fetch some data from that jenkins. For that i'm using

```
HTTP.get('http://xyz.abc/job/test1/job/test2/job/test3/api/json?pretty=true',{auth:"username:password"});
```

For other jenkins which dosen't have compulsory authentications to view the workspace, this above request format works. But when i run this i get:

```
 Exception while invoking method 'GetJobs' Error: unable to verify the first 
  certificate
 I20180124-13:50:48.142(5.5)?     at TLSSocket.<anonymous>(_tls_wrap.js:1103:38)
 I20180124-13:50:48.142(5.5)?     at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
 I20180124-13:50:48.142(5.5)?     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:208:7)
 I20180124-13:50:48.143(5.5)?     at TLSSocket._finishInit(_tls_wrap.js:637:8)
 I20180124-13:50:48.143(5.5)?     at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone(_tls_wrap.js:467:38)
```

I tried to login to that URL from browsers and it was success. But through http.call i'm not able to get the response. Is there any way we can solve this error and make it work?

Comment: What if you change the request from GET to POST?

Comment: Since i want to retrieve data in json format, i thought 'GET' is useful in doing that operation. And 'POST' also gives me same error as 'GET'.